# Вложенные циклы foreach

Tags: php

Как избежать повторного вывода одного и того же при вложенных циклах foreach. Или как реализовать код, чтобы такого не было? Пример кода, где вложенные циклы делают обход файлов:

```
$spisok_files = ftp_nlist($antona_connect, $file_remote);
foreach ($spisok_files as $key => $value_rem) {
    $ftp_size_fil = ftp_size($antona_connect, $file_remote . $value_rem);
    echo "MD5 хэш размера ftp файла " . $value_rem . "- " . $md5_rem = md5($ftp_size_fil) . "<br>";
    $local_scan = scandir($file_local);
    foreach ($local_scan as $key_scan => $value_loc) {
        if (!is_dir($value_loc)) {
            echo "Сравнивают удаленный $value_rem с локальным $value_loc<br>";
            $size_local = filesize($file_local . $value_loc);
            echo "MD5 хэш размера локального файла " . $value_loc . "- " . $md5_loc = md5($size_local) . "<br>";
            if ($md5_loc !== $md5_rem AND $value_rem == $value_loc) {
                echo "Загружаю++++++++++++++++++++++++++<br>";
                ftp_nod_upload($value_loc);
            } else {
                echo "Забиваю-------------------------------<br>";
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я так понял , что цель скрипта - сверить файлы на сервере и на локале.
ТОгда я бы сделал по другому- создал массив файлов на локале с его MD5, то есть в итоге двумерный масив (данные о файл это тоже в массив), далее создал бы такой же массив данных о локальных файлах.

ДАлее проверяем, причем если мы нашли совпадения файлов - тое сть их заливать не надо, то этот файл моно удалить из списка локальных( как бы он найден и он может и ему может соответствовать только 1 файл на сервере - если тут моя логика не верна - то неделай етого). Файлы котороые нада кинуть на сервер собираешь в отдельный массив. После проверки сверки файлов , обрабатываешь массив с файлами которые нада залить . вот впринципе и все.

ЕЩе как можно сделать чтоб патом так не каруселить. Если файлы на сервер можешь заливать только ты (для чего и пишешь скрипт), то на локале с папкой я бы создал txt  файлик, куда и писалбы об изменениях файлов на локале, а потом уже запуск скрипта который читает етот файл и заливает то что нада, по окончании он его перезаписывает, то есть там не должно быть строк

Comment: Первую версию я так и сделал, через учёт файлов на локале и сервере в локальной txt базе. В целом всё получилось, код получился только большой. Потом попробовал это реализовать через md5 без создания баз, код заметно короче и проще. 
За совет спасибо, значит мыслил верно, что очень порадовало.